# Resources for learning Chemistry

Tags: software, reference-request, books

Based on various other Stack exchange site ([Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese), [Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian) and [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)), we adapt this project here for chemistry, since it's a great idea to have all kinds of resources in one place.

---

This is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for learning Chemistry. The lists are a **community maintained project**, hence **everybody** with more than 100 reputation points can contribute edits to the appropriate sections. If you feel something is missing, just fill it in. To avoid multiple answers for similar branches, we decided on a general outline, which is locked, i.e. no new answers can be added.
If you have concerns or questions, you can discuss this list on its parent [meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-doing-learning-chemistry). If they are of a more general concern, you can also [post a new question on chemistry.meta.se](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This procedure is used, so the comment section here does not become too overcrowded. If you do choose the second option, please leave the link to it in the comments to this post.

### Organization

- Answers have a type of resource **each**.
- If possible, state whether the material is directed towards a **beginner**, **intermediate** or an **advanced** audience.
- **Do not** include links that lead to illegal content or sites that host such content. If you see any, please **flag for moderator attention** and choose "other" so you can point us to the content. We'll delete it as soon as we see the flag. (You can of course also delete it yourself. If you do, please flag it anyway, so that we are aware of it. In this case it is crucial you fill in the edit summary with something like: *Removed link to illegal content.*)
- Both free and commercial resources are allowed, but make sure to include a note if they are the latter. Remember the [rules about self-promotion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Include also if registration is required.
- Include links to the sites only, *don't post images*, they would take too much space.
- Add the resources in alphabetical order so they're easier to find.
- For the resources, a short summary is very much appreciated.

*If you have questions about these guidelines, please head to [meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-doing-learning-chemistry) to make yourself heard. The above points are not set in stone and might change in the future.*

### Alphabetical Index

- **(Text)Books:** All books that teach you chemistry with theory and exercises. The subcategories are:

1. [General Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37306/)
2. [Inorganic, Organic and Physical Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37305/)
3. [Analytical Chemistry, Biochemistry and Chemical Biology, Chemical Engineering, Computational and Quantum Chemistry, Theoretical Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37304/)
   *You can add any subcategory to this post if it is missing.*

- [**Online courses and Websites:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37307/) Free or paid services online that teach you chemistry through lessons as well as sites that give help for learning chemistry. They give material, tips, hints, and various help for self-learners or regular students.
- [**Software:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880/) This can be any software ranging from plugins for the browser over mobile apps up to standalone applications for the computer. Pure 2D or 3D visualization programs as well as quantum chemistry programs might not fit in this category, as they are not primarily focused on teaching chemistry.
- [**Video Resources & TV:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37310/) Video resources which help learning chemistry.
- [**References about Nomenclature:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/155812/) Successful communication requires an agreed set of definitions compiled as nomenclature. An example for such compilations are IUPAC's Color Books, named by the color of their book cover.

*Currently those are all categories. If you think, that a new one should be added, please submit an answer in the corresponding [meta thread](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-doing-learning-chemistry). (A comment is probably not sufficient, as it does "bump" the question on the* active *tab.*

Comment: Official chat room for this thread: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29685/discussion-about-resources-for-learning-chemistry (Ping a moderator in [chat] if frozen.)

Answer (score 37):

## Books about Inorganic Chemistry

- **General texts**

  - [Housecroft, C. E.; Sharpe, A. G. *Inorganic Chemistry*, 4th ed.; Prentice Hall: Upper Saddle River, NJ, 2012.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0273742752)
  - [Weller, M.; Overton, T.; Rourke, J.; Armstrong, F. *Inorganic Chemistry*, 6th ed; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2014.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1429299061)
    This is the latest version of the textbook commonly known as *Shriver & Atkins*.
  - [Miessler, G. L.; Fischer, P. J.; Tarr, D. A. *Inorganic Chemistry*, 5th ed.; Prentice Hall: Upper Saddle River, NJ, 2014.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321811054)
    A relatively shorter text, but explains chemical bonding extremely well.
  - [Ghosh, A.; Berg, S. *Arrow Pushing in Inorganic Chemistry: A Logical Approach to the Chemistry
    of the Main-Group Elements*, 1st ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2014.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Arrow+Pushing+in+Inorganic+Chemistry%3A+A+Logical+Approach+to+the+Chemistry+of+the+Main+Group+Elements-p-9781118924532)
    A mechanistic approach to reactions in inorganic chemistry with emphasis on the mechanisms.
  - [Lee, J. D. *Concise Inorganic Chemistry*, 5th ed; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 1999.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Concise+Inorganic+Chemistry%2C+5th+Edition-p-9780632052936)
    A classic introductory inorganic chemistry textbook.
  - [Bauer, G *Handbook of Preparative Inorganic Chemistry*, 2nd ed; Academic Press: New York, 1963](https://archive.org/details/Handbook_of_Preparative_Inorganic_Chemistry_1_2_Brauer)
    A two volume compendium about small-scale syntheses of elements, maingroup and transition element inorganic compounds.

## Books about Organic Chemistry

- **General texts**

  - [Carey, F. A.; Sundberg, R. J. *Advanced Organic Chemistry, Part A: Structure and Mechanisms*, 5th ed.; Springer: New York, 2007.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387683461)
    [Carey, F. A.; Sundberg, R. J. *Advanced Organic Chemistry, Part B: Reactions and Synthesis*, 5th ed.; Springer: New York, 2007.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387683542)
    Carey & Sundberg is a classic two-volume text with an extremely in-depth discussion. Mechanisms are elucidated in great detail (primarily via MO theory, with results from both ab initio and semi-empirical methods), and the exposition of pericyclic reactions is notably excellent. It also contains a great deal of illuminating content on conformational analysis. Definitely not appropriate for a first textbook, but essential reading for advanced undergraduates and above.
  - [Carey, F. A.; Giuliano, R. M. *Organic Chemistry*, 9th ed.; McGraw-Hill: New York, NY, 2014.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073402745)
  - [Clayden, J.; Greeves, N.; Warren, S. *Organic Chemistry*, 2nd ed.; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2012.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199270295)
    Excellent first textbook for organic with lucid explanations. It's worth noting that the first edition, while slightly more verbose, contains more information than the second, where some chapters and sections were cut.
  - [Smith, M. B. *March's Advanced Organic Chemistry: Reactions, Mechanisms, and Structure*, 7th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2013.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470462590)
    A comprehensive book that covers nearly every reaction under the sun, with appropriate references to primary literature. Arguably best used as a reference and not as study material, but it is also surprisingly readable.
  - [Solomons, T. W. Graham; Fryhle, C. B.; *Organic Chemistry*, 10th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2011.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470401419)
    Introductory textbook for organic chemistry.
  - [Wade, L. G. *Organic Chemistry*, 8th ed.; Pearson Education: Glenview, IL, 2013.](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Wade-Organic-Chemistry-8th-Edition/9780321768414.html)
    A systematic introductory textbook for organic chemistry. Follows the traditional functional group approach.
- **Organic synthesis**

  - [Warren, S.; Wyatt, P. *Organic Synthesis: The Disconnection Approach*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2008.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470712368)
    A step-by-step introduction to organic retrosynthetic analysis and the construction of different relations between functional groups. Do also get the accompanying [workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCQ355T) (the solutions are discussed immediately after problems).
  - [Kürti, L.; Czakó, B. *Strategic Applications of Named Reactions in Organic Synthesis*; Elsevier: Amsterdam, 2005.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124297854)
    An incredible compilation of 250 named reactions, with discussion of mechanisms and examples of application to total synthesis. Nearly 10,000 references to primary literature.
  - [Mundy, B. P.; Ellerd, M. G.; Favaloro, F. G., Jr. *Name Reactions and Reagents in Organic Synthesis*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2005.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471228540)
    A reference book for numerous reaction mechanisms and common reagents.
  - [Nicolaou, K. C.; Sorensen, E. J. *Classics in Total Synthesis*; Wiley: Weinheim, Germany, 1996.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527292314)
    Thorough discussion of the retrosynthesis and forward synthesis of 36 molecules, by one of the most well-known synthetic chemists of recent years and (at the time) his Ph.D. student. Examples are taken from almost the entire history of organic synthesis: from Woodward's 1954 synthesis of strychnine to the author's own 1995 synthesis of brevetoxin B. Also check out the sequels, [*Classics in Total Synthesis II*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527306846) and [*Classics in Total Synthesis III*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527329579).
  - [Wuts, P. G. M. *Greene's Protective Groups in Organic Synthesis*, 5th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2014.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118057481)
    Comprehensive listing of protecting groups, protection and deprotection conditions with references to primary literature, and handy reactivity charts which assess the stability of protecting groups towards various reagents and conditions.
  - [Zubrick, James W. *The Organic Chem Lab Survival Manual: A Student's Guide to Techniques*; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2019](https://www.wiley.com/en-af/The+Organic+Chem+Lab+Survival+Manual%3A+A+Student%27s+Guide+to+Techniques%2C+11th+Edition-p-9781119607861).  This primer introduces students to basic equipment and techniques in the organic lab. Topics considered include literature search, general safety, microscale operation, product isolation / purification / characterization (e.g., melting point, IR and NMR), and record keeping.
- **Spectroscopy**

  - [Pavia, D. L.; Lampman, G. M.; Kriz, G. S.; Vyvyan, J. A. *Introduction to Spectroscopy*, 5th ed.; Cengage Learning: Stamford, CT, 2015.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0495114782)
    Excellent introductory text with good coverage of all the typical structure determination techniques: elemental analysis, NMR, IR, MS, and UV-Vis.
  - [Silverstein, R. M.; Webster, F. X.; Kiemle, D. J.; Bryce, D.L. *Spectrometric Identification of Organic Compounds*, 8th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2014.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470616377)
    Perhaps a slightly more in-depth discussion than Pavia, but without sacrificing any clarity. Includes a large number of tables and charts of spectroscopic data, making it also very valuable as a reference.
  - [Claridge, T. D. W. *High-Resolution NMR Techniques in Organic Chemistry*, 3rd ed.; Elsevier: Amsterdam, 2016.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0080999867)
    A much more involved (graduate level) discussion of how NMR experiments are designed and how we extract information from them. Along with the more physchem-oriented NMR books, this is recommended for those who want to know what is actually going on in their NMR machine.
  - [Field, L. D.; Li, H. L.; Magill, A. M. *Organic Structures from Spectra*, 6th edition; Wiley, 2020](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Organic+Structures+from+Spectra%2C+6th+Edition-p-9781119524847)  Brief theory of UV-Vis, MS, IR, and NMR followed by training sets of experimentally recorded data with focus on the *combination* of these techniques in the process of structure elucidation.  Instructors may obtain an answer key.
  - [Field, L. D.; Li, H. L.; Magill, A. M. *Organic Structures from 2D NMR Spectra*, Wiley, 2016](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Organic+Structures+from+2D+NMR+Spectra%2C+Set-p-9781119073703) While (newer editions) of their other book about structure elucidation contains *some* 2D NMR spectra, this book now emphasises the training how to interpret correlation NMR spectra.  Equally available as instructor's guide including the answers.

## Books about Physical Chemistry

- **General texts**

  - [Atkins, P.; de Paula, J. *Physical Chemistry*, 10th ed; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2014.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019969740X)
    Classic physical chemistry textbook, but can sometimes be difficult to follow, especially for first-time students.
  - [Atkins, P.; de Paula, J. *Elements of Physical Chemistry*, 7th ed.; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2016.](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/elements-of-physical-chemistry-9780198727873?cc=in&lang=en&)
    A less detailed book than *Physical Chemistry*. Can be used for introductory physical chemistry courses.
  - [Engel, T.; Reid, P. *Physical Chemistry*, 3rd ed.; Prentice Hall: Upper Saddle River, NJ, 2012.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032181200X)
  - [Levine, I. N. *Physical Chemistry*, 6th ed.; McGraw-Hill: New York, 2009.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071321217)
- **Statistical mechanics**

  - [Chandler, D. *Introduction to Modern Statistical Mechanics*; Oxford UP:Oxford, U.K., 1987](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Modern-Statistical-Mechanics-Chandler/dp/0195042778)
    Useful for undergraduate and early graduate study of both classical and quantum statistical mechanics, as well as for reference.
  - [McQuarrie, D. A. *Statistical Mechanics*; University Science Books: Mill Valley, CA, 2000.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1891389157)
- **Nuclear magnetic resonance**

  - [Keeler, J. *Understanding NMR Spectroscopy,* 2nd ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2010.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470746084)
    An extremely accessible and readable introduction to the theory behind NMR experiments. Describes nearly every important aspect of NMR, from basic quantum mechanics to the vector model, product operators, and a range of NMR experiments. It seems to be a conscious choice on the part of the author to not delve too deep into the quantum mechanics, in the interests of clarity and understanding.
  - [Levitt, M.H. *Spin Dynamics,* 2nd ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2008.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008VQQLQ2)
    An extremely in-depth treatment of the quantum mechanics of NMR, which goes well beyond the level of Keeler's book.
  - [Gunther, H. *NMR Spectroscopy,* 3rd ed.; Wiley: Weinheim, Germany, 2013.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527330003)
- **Computational and Quantum Chemistry**

  - [Levine, I. N. *Quantum Chemistry,* 7th ed.; Pearson: Upper Saddle River, NJ, 2012.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321803450)
    This book acts as a first introduction to quantum chemistry and computational methods for students who do not have prior experience with the field.
  - [Atkins, P. W.; Friedman, R. S. *Molecular Quantum Mechanics,* 5th ed.; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2010.](https://www.amazon.de/Molecular-Quantum-Mechanics-Peter-Atkins/dp/0199541426)
    Realizes a more extensive coverage than Levine.
  - [Cohen-Tannoudji, C.; Diu, B.; Laloe, F. *Quantum Mechanics;* Wiley: New York, 1977.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047116433X)
    This book is a very good book on quantum mechanics that is often used by physics majors to learn the subject. Reading it is necessary if a better understanding than that provided by previous books is desired.
  - [McWeeny, R. *Symmetry*; Dover, 2002.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486421821)
  - [Parr, R. G.; Yang, W. *Density-Functional Theory of Atoms and Molecules;* Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 1996.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195092767)
    The first book on DFT and by leaders in the field, still unbeatable.
  - [Jensen, F. *Introduction to Computational Chemistry*; Wiley, 2007](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470011874)
    This books treats the computational methods at a beginner level.
  - [Szabo, A.; Ostlund, N. S. *Modern Quantum Chemistry: Introduction to Advanced Electronic Structure Theory*; Dover, 1996](https://www.amazon.de/Modern-Quantum-Chemistry-Introduction-Electronic/dp/0486691861)
  - [Helgaker, T.; Jorgensen, P; Olsen, J. Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118531477).

    This is the reference book on wavefunction methods.
  - [Cancès, E; Defranceschi, M; Kutzelnigg, W.; Le Bris, C.; Maday, Y. *Computational Quantum Chemistry: A primer*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570865903100038).

    A sophisticated mathematical analysis of wavefunction methods and density functional theory.
- **Solid State Chemistry and Crystallography**

  - West, A. R. *Solid State Chemistry and Its Applications*, 2nd ed.; John Wiley & Sons, Inc: Chichester, West Sussex, **2014**.
  - Simon, S. H. *The Oxford Solid State Basics*, 1st ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford, **2013**.
  - Smart, L.; Moore, E. *Solid State Chemistry: An Introduction*, 4th ed.; CRC Press: Boca Raton, FL, **2012**.
  - Tilley, R. J. D. *Understanding Solids: The Science of Materials*; J. Wiley: Chichester, West Sussex, England; Hoboken, NJ, USA, **2004**.
  - [Hoffmann, R. *How Chemistry and Physics Meet in the Solid State*; DOI: 10.1002/anie.198708461](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/anie.198708461).

    Learning solid state theory is difficult for a chemist in part because it is primarily ridden by a different community (physicists) that have a different language and way to understand bonding. This review helps in bridging the gap.
  - [Ashcroft, N. S.; Mermin, N. Solid State Physics; Cengage Learning, 1976](https://www.amazon.de/Solid-State-Physics-Neil-Ashcroft/dp/0030839939/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1535228076&sr=1-1&keywords=ashcroft%20solid%20state%20physics).

    This textbook is primary reference to learn solid state physics.
  - [Evarestov, R. A. *Quantum Chemistry of Solids: LCAO Treatment of Crystals and Nanostructures*, Springer, 2012](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642303555).
  - [Fundamentals of Crystallography, 3th ed., Oxford University Press, 2011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198738684)
  - [Müller, Ulrich *Symmetry Relationships between Crystal Structures.
    Applications of Crystallographic Group Theory in Crystal Chemistry*, 2nd ed., Oxford University Press, 2017](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/symmetry-relationships-between-crystal-structures-9780198807209?lang=en&cc=de)

    A rigorous yet accessible explanation of the foundations of crystallography and symmetry relationships with a large collection of exercises to practice. Good for self-study.
  - Müller, U. *Anorganische Strukturchemie*, 6., aktualisierte Aufl., unveränd. Nachdr.; Studium; Vieweg + Teubner: Wiesbaden, **2009**. (in German)
  - Dronskowski, R. Computational Chemistry of Solid State Materials: A Guide for Materials Scientists, Chemists, Physicists and Others; Wiley-VCH: Weinheim, **2005**.
- **Molecular Orbital Theory**

  - [Fleming, I. *Molecular Orbitals and Organic Chemical Reactions: Student Edition*; Wiley: Chichester, 2009.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470684306)

    A readable introduction to molecular orbital theory with an emphasis on its application to simple organic chemical reactions (S<sub>N</sub>1/S<sub>N</sub>2 etc). Suitable for undergraduates wanting a more detailed understanding of organic reactivity. Also widely considered to be *the* book for the molecular orbital treatment of pericyclic reactions.
  - [Fleming, I. *Molecular Orbitals and Organic Chemical Reactions: Reference edition*; Wiley: Chichester, 2009.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Molecular+Orbitals+and+Organic+Chemical+Reactions%2C+Reference+Edition-p-9780470746585)

    An expanded version of *Molecular Orbitals and Organic Chemical Reactions: Student Edition* with a full list of references and additional coverage of some material. More suited to graduate students / instructors who might want to read deeper into a topic.
  - [Albright, T. A.; Burdett, J. K.; Whangbo, M-H. *Orbital Interactions in Chemistry*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2013.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Orbital+Interactions+in+Chemistry%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471080398)

    Arguably the best book on the subject, both in terms of depth (some mathematical treatment of the topics) and coverage (organic and inorganic molecules are discussed). Given the size (over 800 pages), Albright is more of a reference text than Fleming which can easily be read cover-to-cover, and the level of discussion is more geared towards graduate students / undergraduates in later years who already have some understanding of molecular orbitals.
  - [Jean, Y. *Molecular Orbitals of Transition Metal Complexes*; Oxford, 2005.](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/molecular-orbitals-of-transition-metal-complexes-9780198530930?cc=gb&lang=en&)

    An undergraduate level textbook covering the fundamentals of molecular orbital theory applied to transition metal complexes. The derivations of the MO diagrams for various coordination geometries is provided along with a chapter on 'applications' of MO theory such as how complexes react.
- **Electrochemistry**

  - [Elgrishi, N. *et al.* *A Practical Beginner’s Guide to Cyclic Voltammetry*; *J. Chem. Educ.* 2018, *95*, 197–206.](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361) (open access)

    A short introduction teaching the very basics about CV's theory, supplemented with tips and warnings for pitfalls recording and interpreting the experimental data.  The supplementary information contains five training modules to walk through the more typical minutiae one encounters.

Comment: For Organic chemistry I really like "Organic Chemistry" by Brown, Iverson, Anslyn and Foote

Comment: Umm...Paula Bruice would be a good book for beginners..to get the basics clear..and for further reading Peter Sykes is also good.

Comment: I found McQuarrie's Quantum Chemistry to be very helpful for quantum mechanics. Especially the "math chapters", which reviewed pertinent math techniques before they are required for each quantum topic.

Answer (score 27):

## Video Resources (online)

- [The University of Nottingham's Periodic Videos](http://www.periodicvideos.com/)
  The periodic table of videos includes introductions to all elements. The molecular videos section focuses on interesting chemical reactions. Apart from having quite some entertaining value, they visualise a lot of reactions that can only safely be carried out in a laboratory environment. The videos are hosted on their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/periodicvideos).
- [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/)
  Khan Academy is a site, which is explaining many different subjects to all who are eager to learn. Those subjects are explained through video lessons on youtube, on which the speaker uses a virtual blackboard to draw and clarify the explanations for a deeper understanding. As those videos cover basic theories, it is probably more helpful for the beginner as for the advanced student. There are two channels for chemistry:

  - [Khan Academy - Chemistry](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry)
    Did you know that everything is made out of chemicals? Chemistry is the study of matter: its composition, properties, and reactivity. This material roughly covers a first-year high school or college course, and a good understanding of algebra is helpful.
  - [Khan Academy - Organic Chemistry](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry)
    Topics covered in college organic chemistry course are explained. Basic understanding of basic high school or college chemistry assumed (although there is some review).
- [Organic Chemistry 1 by University of New Orleans](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/organic-chemistry-1/id561733804?ign-mpt=uo%3D8)
  This is the first semester of sophomore Organic Chemistry.This course completes most chemistry requirements for pre-professional degree programs and science degrees.  This course will cover the introduction of basic fundamental topics of organic chemistry.  Specifically the structure-activity relationship and spectroscopy of organic functional groups will be investigated.  Starting with simple organic models, we will cover structures of organic chemicals from basic connectivity to three- dimensional spatial alignments.  Nomenclature and spectroscopy of the different groups will be covered along with reactivity of those groups.
- [Organic Chemistry 2 by University of New Orleans](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/organic-chemistry-2/id561733766?ign-mpt=uo%3D8)
  This is the second semester of sophomore Organic Chemistry.  This course completes most chemistry requirements for pre-professional degree programs and science degrees. This course will cover the reactions, mechanisms and properties of various functional groups including dienes, arenes, carbonyls, carboxylic acid and their derivatives, phenols, amines as well as biochemicals such as carbohydrates, lipids, amino acids and proteins.
- [General Organic Chemistry 2 Course by Arizona State University](http://chm234.asu.edu/top.html)
  This is the complete set materials used in the second semester of Organic Chemistry. It includes home works, video lectures, notes, exams, etc.
- [Chemistry Courses by University of Massachusetts - Boston](http://ocw.umb.edu/chemistry.html)
  Offers both Organic Chemistry 1 and 2.
- [“Organic Chemistry – Structure and Reactivity” by UC Berkeley professor Peter C. Vollhardt](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-XXv-cvA_iAqa_0qj7SlOy3KJHcgRgrb)
  An Excellent Resource for Organic Chemistry. It is **different** from other courses, in the manner the of approach to the topic.
- [Organic Reactions and Pharmaceuticals by Professor Hardinger, UCLA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBBWhBSFC1Q&feature=list_related&playnext=1&list=SP4BE4AAFBFECDB2F8)
  The lectures are lot more exciting than others due to the method of teaching of the professor.Organic Reactions and Pharmaceuticals is a class that provides an in-depth analysis of organic reactions, nucleophilic and electrophilic substitutions and additions; electrophilic aromatic substitutions, carbonyl reactions, catalysis, molecular basis of drug action, and organic chemistry of pharmaceuticals.
- [UC Irvine OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.uci.edu/collections/open_chemistry.html)
  This is *mother of all resources*. *OpenChem* by *UCI* offers a course on each and every aspect of chemistry. It has 6 different courses for organic chemistry whose levels vary from undergraduate to graduate.
- The youtube channel of the [Australian and New Zealand Society for Magnetic Resonance](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBJcwZxXugv5PgzFgm-n2eA)
  Presented briefly by Kwan *et al.* in the [*Journal of Chemical Education*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jchemed.8b00523), basic and advanced principles of NMR / MRI and EPR are lectured.
- [MIT 5.60 Thermodynamics and Kinetics, Spring 2008](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA62087102CC93765)
  The above course is available as a part of MIT OCW. Links in the description of video lectures includes lecture notes, readings, exams and course materials available for download. Covers a basic to intermediate introduction to thermodynamics and kinetics at the undergraduate level.
- [TMP Chem](https://www.youtube.com/c/TMPChem)
  Trent M. Parker's youtube channel about quantum chemistry, spectroscopy, chemical thermodynamics, kinetics, theoretical/computational chemistry, reviewing mathematics for physical chemistry.  Computations centre on Python.

## Television

- [Uranium- Twisting the Dragon's Tail](http://www.pbs.org/program/uranium-twisting-dragons-tail/)
  Host and physicist Dr. Derek Muller unlocks the mysteries of uranium, one of the Earth's most controversial elements. Born from the collapse of a star, uranium has brought hope, progress and destruction. It has revolutionized society, from medicine to warfare. It is an element that has profoundly shaped the past, will change the future and will exist long after humans have left the Earth.

Answer (score 23):

## Books about Analytical Chemistry

- [Schwarzenbach, G.; Flaschka, H. A. *Complexometric Titrations*; Methuen: London, 1957 (translated by H. Irving in 1969).](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jps.3030470241)
- [Skoog, D. A.; West, D. M.; Holler, F. J.; Crouch, S. R. *Fundamentals of Analytical Chemistry*, 9th ed.; Brooks/Cole: Pacific Grove, CA, 2013.](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8bIWAAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions)
- Elgrishi *et al.*, *A Practical Beginner’s Guide to Cyclic Voltammetry*, *J. Chem. Educ.* 2018, 95, 2, 197-206, [doi 10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361). A short introduction, indicating tips and pitfalls, published as open access.

---

## Books about Biochemistry and Chemical Biology

- [Voet, D.; Voet, J. G. *Biochemistry*, 4th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2011.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Biochemistry%2C+4th+Edition-p-9780470570951)
- [Nelson, D.; Cox, M. *Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry*, 7th ed.;  Macmillan Higher Education: Houndmills, UK, 2017.](https://www.macmillanlearning.com/Catalog/product/lehningerprinciplesofbiochemistry-seventhedition-nelson)
- [Berg, J.; Tymoczko, J.; Gatto Jr., G; Stryer L. *Biochemistry*, 9th ed.; Macmillan Higher Education: Houndmills, UK, 2019.](https://macmillanlearning.com/Catalog/product/biochemistry-ninthedition-stryer)

---

## Books about Chemical Engineering

- The probably most comprehensive reference for chemical engineering is the [McGraw-Hill Chemical Engineering Series](http://www.librarything.com/tag/McGraw+Hill+Chemical+engineering+series), which contains more than you should know as a student. After all a strong knowledge in all areas of chemistry is necessary. As an engineer, and a chemist especially, if you are looking for sizing operations, you'll need to think about details, which are not in the books unfortunately.
  For the related question, see: [What are introductory level books on chemical engineering?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/84637/)
- The [Visual Encyclopedia of Chemical Engineering](http://encyclopedia.che.engin.umich.edu/) is a project hosted by the Department of Chemical Engineering, University of Michigan.  By text, illustration, and video, typical applications of devices and processes, their advantages and disadvantages are presented.  Equally, means to monitor processes are shown and literature references (pointing e.g. to Perry's Chemical Engineering Handbook) provided.

---

## Books about Computational Chemistry and Quantum Chemistry

### Introductory

- Atkins, P.; Friedman, R. *Molecular Quantum Mechanics*, 5th ed.; Oxford UP: Oxford, U.K., 2010.
  [Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/molecular-quantum-mechanics-9780199541423),
  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199541426).
  `<Description>`
- Cramer, C. J. *Essentials of Computational Chemistry: Theories and Models*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2004.
  [Wiley](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470091827.html),
  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470091827).
  `<Description>`
- Jensen, J.H. *Molecular Modeling Basics*; CRC Press: Boca Raton, FL, 2010.
  [CRC Press](https://www.crcpress.com/Molecular-Modeling-Basics/Jensen/9781420075267),
  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420075268).
  `<Description>`
- Levine, I. N. *Quantum Chemistry*, 7th ed.; Prentice Hall: Upper Saddle River, NJ, 2014.
  [Prentice Hall](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Levine-Quantum-Chemistry-7th-Edition/PGM78512.html),
  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321803450).
  `<Description>`
- McQuarrie, D. A. *Quantum Chemistry*, 2nd ed.; University Science Books: Mill Valley, CA, 2007.
  [University Science Books](http://www.uscibooks.com/mcqqc2.htm) (https not available),
  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1891389505).
  `<Description>`
- Koch, W.; Holthausen , M. C. *A Chemist’s Guide to Density Functional Theory*, 2nd ed.; Wiley-VCH: Weinheim, 2001. ISBNs: 3-527-30372-3 (Softcover); 3-527-60004-3 (Electronic). DOI: [10.1002/3527600043](https://doi.org/10.1002/3527600043).

  Introductory text for chemists familiar with conventional quantum mechanics. The book introduces density functional theory: its basis, concepts, terms, implementation, and performance in diverse applications. This includes the usage of DFT for structure, energy, and molecular property computations, as well as reaction mechanism studies, etc.

### Intermediate

- Allen, M. P.; Tildesley, D. J. *Computer Simulation of Liquids*; Clarendon Press: Oxford, U.K., 1987. `<Links>`.
  `<Description>`
- Bachrach, S. M. *Computational Organic Chemistry*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, 2014.
  [Wiley](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118291921,subjectCd-CHD0.html) (https not available),
  [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118291921).
  `<Description>`
- Jensen, F. *Introduction to Computational Chemistry*, 3rd ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2017.
  [Wiley](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118825993.html) (https not available),
  [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118825993).
  Provides a good overview/introduction to many aspects of QC. The focus is on concepts, not on mathematical rigour.
- Szabo, A.; Ostlund, N.S. *Modern Quantum Chemistry: Introduction to Advanced Electronic Stucture Theory*; Dover: Mineola, NY, 1989 (revised in 1996).
  [Dover Publications](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486691861.html) (https not available),
  [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486691861).
  A classic introduction to the ab initio wave-function-based methods of electronic structure theory. Contains detailed discussions of the Hartree-Fock and post-Hartree-Fock methods such as Møller–Plesset perturbation theory, configuration interaction, and coupled cluster. The latter discussions are correct, but sometimes a bit dated.
- Tuckerman M.E; *Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Molecular Simulation*, 1st ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford, U.K., 2010.
  [Oxford UP](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/statistical-mechanics-9780198525264),
  [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198525265).
- Helgaker T.; Jørgensen P.; Olsen J. *Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory*; Wiley: Chichester, U.K. 2000.
  [Wiley](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471967556.html)
  (https not available), [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118531477).
  An in-depth description of the inner workings of all the common modern wavefunction based methods - Hartree-Fock and multi-reference self-consistent field, perturbation theory, configuration interation and coupled cluster.

---

## Books about Theoretical Chemistry

- Cotton, F. A. *Chemical Applications of Group Theory*, 3rd ed.; Wiley: New York, 1990.
- Vincent, A. *Molecular Symmetry and Group Theory: A Programmed Introduction to Chemical Applications*, 2nd ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2000.

Comment: related: [List of important publications in chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_chemistry) on Wikipedia

Comment: There is an excellent course available for free at compmatphys.org . I am not sure if the videos will be available afterwards.

Comment: Can someone mention what are the standard undergraduate level (up to 4th year) analytical chemistry textbooks used in Germany?

Answer (score 22):

## Online Courses

- [Chemistry LibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/)
  This collection was formerly known as UC Davis' ChemWiki: The Dynamic Chemistry Hypertext. It is a collaborative approach toward chemistry education where an Open Access textbook environment is constantly being written and re-written by students and faculty members resulting in a free Chemistry textbook to supplant conventional paper-based books.
- [Jim Clark's Chemguide](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/)
  An in-depth overview of many areas of basic chemistry, including organic, inorganic, physical, and instrumental. Forgoes mathematical treatments of chemistry in favor of teaching an intuitive understanding for how chemical systems behave. Targeted at UK A-level students, but useful for anyone who wants to shore up their fundamentals.
- [Virtual Textbook of Organic Chemistry](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/intro1.htm)
  A very useful introduction to principles in organic chemistry and the reactions of common functional groups.

## Websites

- [IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology - the Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/)
  A concise compendium of the most common terminology that is used in chemical and related sciences.
- [NIST Chemistry WebBook](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/)
  A searchable database for standard reference data of chemical compounds by the National Institute of Standards and Technologies.
- [Symmetry@Otterbein](https://symotter.org/)
  An interactive tutorial (by Otterbein University) about molecular, as well as crystallographic symmetry.
- [A Hypertext Book of Crystallographic Space Group Diagrams and Tables](http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/mainmenu.htm)
  The Space group diagrams you find in the in the International Tables of Crystallography.  It equally considers standard settings (e.g., $P2_1/c$) and alternatives like $P2_1/a$, $P2_1/n$, $B2_1/a$, $B2_1/d$ -- all of the  filed under #14.
- [Online Dictionary of Crystallography](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Main_Page)
  The dictionary is provided by the International Union of Crystallography (IUCr). It is a curated glossary about the more frequently met crystallographic concepts.
- [Organic Chemistry Lab Techniques](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Organic_Chemistry_Lab_Techniques_(Nichols))
  An illustrated collection of basic techniques met in the organic chemistry lab.  The content naturally shows some overlaps with / complements to print primers like the one by [Zubrick](https://www.wiley.com/en-af/The+Organic+Chem+Lab+Survival+Manual%3A+A+Student%27s+Guide+to+Techniques%2C+11th+Edition-p-9781119607861).
- [Organic Chemistry Data & Info](https://organicchemistrydata.org/)
  A site of general interest about chemical and reaction data, cross-link to literature references (like the Hans Reich collection) useful for the chemist in the lab as well as educators/students.  Moderated by the Division of Organic Chemistry of the American Chemical Society.
- [hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu - Chemistry](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/chemcon.html)
  A hierarchical set of compact cheat-cards, navigated along a "bubble tree", intended for quick learning/reminding/overview of basics of many chemical concepts, rules and topics.
- [Wikipedia Chemical Structure Explorer](https://wikipedia.cheminfo.org/)
  Query more than 20k chemicals in the English edition of Wikipedia by drawing a structure which either is *a substructure*, or *exactly* the structure you look for, or is just *similar* to the one in mind.  If there is a match, the lower part of the page displays the corresponding entry in Wikipedia.

Comment: Is there a clean difference between an online course a website, or is it somewhat fuzzy?

Comment: For me, the online courses are a special subset of websites that are explicitly for teaching conceptual stuff and not only for giving some information. E.g., the mentioned Goldbook and the Webbook both give information from which you can learn, but they are not teaching like what you'd expect from a school lesson. And then there are sites like Khan Acadamy on youtube, which besides other subjects is about teaching chemistry and should be classified as an online course. But I guess you are right, when saying it can be quite fuzzy. (Please ask about such things in the meta thread next time.)

Comment: Another great website is the eBook [*Principles of General Chemistry*](https://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/principles-of-general-chemistry-v1.0/index.html)

Answer (score 20):

## Software

- [ChemOffice Professional](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/Ensemble_for_Chemistry/ChemOffice/ChemOfficeProfessional/)
  **Commercial software** for drawing molecular structures, 3D models and many more. High price but most higher education institutes will provide students/staff with free institutional licenses. The molecular sketcher now has a free online version (built using HTML$5$ and JS): [ChemDraw online](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html)
- [MarvinSketch](https://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/) (desktop) & [MarvinJS](https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/demo.html) (web)
  **Freeware** (closed-source) for drawing molecular structures with a wide feature set. In addition to just being able to draw Lewis structures, the software includes plugins to name what you have drawn (systematic/traditional), predict properties, change atom and bond properties, generate stereoisomers, and much more. Desktop version is Java based so works on Mac, Windows, Linux.
- [ChemDoodle](https://www.chemdoodle.com/)
  **Commercial software** for 2D and 3D molecular structures and diagrams and much more. Also has versions for tablet/mobile. An online free version of ChemDoodle is here: [ChemDoodle Web Components](https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher/)
- [ACD/ChemSketch](http://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/)
  **Commercial software** for Windows only. Includes a **free version** with fewer features.
- [chem*f*ig](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig)
  **Free** $\mathrm\LaTeX$ package distributed under [the LATEX Project Public License 1.3c](https://ctan.org/license/lppl1.3c) developed by [Christian Tellechea](https://ctan.org/author/tellechea?lang=en) for creating 2D chemical structures with seamless integration into any type of a document, from a standalone illustration to a textbook or a poster. Since [Ti*k*Z](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is used for graphics generation, the functionality of `chemfig` can be greatly extended. PDF output can also be rasterized by using external tools such as [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/). Also, see [chem*f*ig questions on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemfig).
- [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc)
  **Free, open source** software for generating 3D models and computational chemistry.
- [GAMESS](http://www.msg.ameslab.gov/gamess/capabilities.html)
  **Free** ab initio molecular quantum chemistry program.
- [ORCA](https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/app.php/portal)
  **Free for academic use** ab initio/DFT quantum chemistry program. Has a nice tutorial on basic molecular modelling [here](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/).
- [Open Babel: The Open Source Chemistry Toolbox](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page)
  **Free** "Open Babel is a chemical toolbox designed to speak the many languages of chemical data. It's an open, collaborative project allowing anyone to search, convert, analyze, or store data from molecular modeling, chemistry, solid-state materials, biochemistry, or related areas."
- [RDKit: Open-Source Cheminformatics Software](http://rdkit.org/)
- [Odyssey by Wavefunction](https://www.wavefun.com/research-odyssey)
  **Commercial software** designed to be used for teaching and learning chemistry. Includes high quality molecular simulations of many materials, in-built virtual labs. Excellent animations of many physical and chemical processes.

Comment: Related questions: - [What free software exists to view molecule pictures within a file explorer?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13592/4945) - [How do I take chemistry notes on Mac?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10732) - [How do I make 3d molecular graphics similar to those shown on Wikipedia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/74546/4945)

Comment: Also related on our meta: [Software to name compounds](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4066/5026)

Answer (score 19):

## Books about General Chemistry

- Atkins, P. W.; Jones, L. L.; Laverman, L. E. *Chemical Principles: The Quest for Insight*, 6th ed.; W. H. Freeman: New York, 2012.
- Silberberg, M.; Amateis, P. *Chemistry: The Molecular Nature of Matter and Change*, 7th ed.; McGraw-Hill: New York, 2014.
- Oxtoby, D. W.; Gillis, H. P.; Campion, A. *Principles of Modern Chemistry*, 8th ed.; Cengage Learning: Boston, MA, 2015.
- Zumdahl, S. S.; Zumdahl, S. A. *Chemistry*, 9th ed.; Brooks/Cole: Pacific Grove, CA, 2013.
- Whitten, K. W.; Davis, R. E.; Peck, L.; Stanley, G. G. *Chemistry*, 10th ed.; Brooks/Cole: Pacific Grove, CA, 2013.
- Munowitz, M. *Principles of Chemistry*, W. W. Norton and Co.: New York, NY, 2000.

Answer (score 6):

## References about Nomenclature

Successful communication requires an agreed set of definitions compiled as nomenclature.  An example for such compilations are IUPAC's [Color Books](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/color-books/), named by the color of their book cover.  Below, they are listed in alphabetic order of their color.

- Favre, H. A. Powell W. H. (eds.) [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013, IUPAC Blue book*, RSC Publishing](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/9780854041824)

  It is noteworthy that there is a searchable compilation of these rules on-line prepared by G. P. Moss [here](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/BlueBook/).

  The sub-set about *substitutive nomenclature* is nicely illustrated by Hellwich *et al.* in the [*Brief guide to the nomenclature of organic chemistry*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/html) as open access publication, altogether with a   four-page [SI (pdf)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/downloadAsset/suppl/j_pac-2019-0104_suppl.pdf) summary this article.
- McNaught, A. D. and Wilkinson, A. (eds.) [*Compendium of Chemical Terminology, The Gold Book*](http://www.old.iupac.org/publications/books/author/mcnaught.html), Blackwell Science, Oxford 1997.  The perhaps most elemental compilation about terms, synonyms, acronyms, and abbreviations by IUPAC equally may be consulted as [online reference](https://goldbook.iupac.org/).
- Cohen, E. R. *et al.* (eds.) [*Quantities, Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry, IUPAC Green Book*](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-0-85404-433-7).  A joint effort by IUPAC, IUPAP, and ISO about quantities, constants, units and their recommended symbolization.  The conversion of units, scientific typography and uncertainty are addressed, too.  The content of the second reprint is available [online (pdf)](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IUPAC-GB3-2012-2ndPrinting-PDFsearchable.pdf). Equally, Stohner and Quack prepared a four-page [summary (pdf)](https://iupac.org/publications/ci/2011/3304/July11_green-sup-4p.pdf).
- Inczedy, J.; Lengyel, T. and Ure, A. M. [*IUPAC Compendium on Analytical Nomenclature, Definitive Rules 1997*](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/orangebook/) 3rd edition, Blackwell Science, 1998. Equally known as *Orange Book*, it addresses topics like the (statistical) representation of results, terms and definitions of classical wet chemistry like titrimetry, thermo- and electrochemical analysis, separations (chromatography and extraction), spectroscopic and spectrometric techniques; kinetic, radiochemical or surface analytical characterizations; as well as quality assurance.  The publication of its fourth edition is scheduled for January 27th, 2023 ([landing page](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-1-78262-947-4)).

  Between 2000 and 2003, IUPAC's Analytical Chemistry Division set up a public searchable [online compendium](http://media.iupac.org/publications/analytical_compendium/).  To ease the compilation of .pdf files, there is a [searchable index](http://media.iupac.org/publications/analytical_compendium/AlphaIndex.html).  There are concepts considered important (PCA / principal component analysis, PLS / partial least squares, or chemometrics) for which the current edition does not (yet) contain a proper dedicated keyword.
- Jones, R. G. *et al.* [*Compendium of Polymer Terminology and Nomenclature, IUPAC Recommendations 2008*](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-0-85404-491-7), RSC Publishing, 2009.
  The *Purple Book* addresses both general as well as specific terms about the nomenclature of polymers, their graphical representation.  In addition, copolymers and blends of polymers; liquid crystals; sols, gels, networks, inorganic organic hybrid materials; reactions and aging of polymers are among the topics addressed.

  Since June 2014, there is searchable [online pdf](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ONLINE-IUPAC-PB2-Online-June2014.pdf) compendium by IUPAC, too.
- Connelly, N. G.; Damhus, T.; Hartshorn, R. M.; Hutton, A. T. (eds.) [*Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations 2005*](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-0-85404-438-2), RSC publishing, 2005.  The *Red Book* compiles the rules about elements, isotopes, simple inorganic compounds, coordination compounds, metalorganic compounds, and solids.

  There is a freely available [online release (pdf)](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Red_Book_2005.pdf) by IUPAC, as well as a [public site](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/bibliog/RBcorrect.html) about errors and updates.  Similar to the *Blue Book*, there equally is a [*Brief guide to the nomenclature of inorganic chemistry*](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2014-0718) with examples of application illustrated in colour, as well as a [4-page summary (pdf)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2014-0718/downloadAsset/suppl/pac-2014-0718_Suppl.pdf).
- Férard, G.; Dybkaer, R.; Fuentes-Arderiu X. [*Compendium of Terminology and Nomenclature of Properties Clinical Laboratory Sciences, Recommendations 2016*](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-1-78262-107-2), RCS publishing, 2016.  The *Silver Book* is a joint effort by IUPAC and IFCC, and to be understood as one interface between laboratory scientists and medical professionals.

  A [4-page summary (pdf)](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Silverbook_concise-summary2017.pdf) is available.
- Liébecq, C. *Biochemical Nomenclature and Related Documents*, 2nd edition, Portland Press, 1992.  For this reference known as *White Book*, G.P. Moss set up an on-line [companion site](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/bibliog/white.html).

If used critically, the non-exhaustive listing about [software to name [organic] compounds](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/software-to-name-compounds) mentioned in a comment by `@Gaurang Tandon` may be of interest, too.